# Verbose Help Section

Tags: interaction-design, help, maps

I am working on a government mapping application. My boss requests (requires) a help/directions documentation on the map and I came up with the following landing page:

[image]

I find this verbose, futhermore, the "On Results Tab" section would require the user to recall this information. I don't expect the average user to read any of this, let alone recall it.

Here is the resultant state of the map UI:

[image]

I believe I have enough affordances and feedback to completely eliminate the "On Results Tab" help section (and there is a help button that regurgitates this information).

How would you structure the landing page "help"?

[Working Demo](http://gis.leg.mn/iMaps/districts-webGL/)

**UPDATED** Alternative, certainly cleaner:

[image]

Comment: I agree with your initial suggestion to eliminate the "On Results Tab". I wouldn't change anything else.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with eliminating the 'On Results Tab', I can't imagine anyone would ever read it.  I would look at moving the other three controls you have on there, and grouping them all together.

It's a bit of a 'treasure hunt' when you say 'look out for these icons' - treasure hunts aren't always bad, but in this case it's a bit weird.

If you had the three controls grouped together, overlayed on the map, they immediately become more obvious, and visually it's more appealing.

Sure it'll take up a little bit of real estate, but in my opinion worth it.

Comment: This is really good feedback. I typically put similar grouped controls in the top-right corner of the map in all my maps, however this time I made that little layers pull-out tab (and I'm kind of married to it at this point), so I'm not sure I can come up with a good scheme to apply this, maybe grouped with the zoom controls? +1